# Is there an equivalent of Spring Cloud Stream in .Net or .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Java project that needs to be rewritten in C# .Net Core. The Java app is currently deployed on cloud using SCS. The concept of stream looks smooth as we can easily visualize the flow of data there. It would be nice to have something similar available in .Net/Core. I tried Google, but couldn't get any useful info on this.

Comment: You can take a look at http://reactivex.io/ , maybe that gets closer to what you want.

Comment: Not that I know of, at least nothing has been communicated/collaborated with us. I think you're referring to something similar to what we used to have - Spring.NET.

Comment: https://steeltoe.io/ by Pivotal for other equivalents of Spring Cloud

Answer (score 1):

[Steeltoe](https://steeltoe.io/) Stream Support:

- https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/steeltoe/issues/128
- https://docs.steeltoe.io/articles/releases/steeltoe-3-1-minor-release-major-deal.html

> This is an Epic, that will track all the work being done for our Streams feature.
>
> Steeltoe Streams will be similar to the functionality that Spring Streams brings. Steeltoe Streams will be used for building highly scalable event-driven .NET microservices connected with shared messaging systems.

[Steeltoe OSS](https://github.com/steeltoeoss): Cloud Native .NET Applications - Friend of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud.

Developed by WMware / Pivotal - https://hub.docker.com/u/steeltoeoss/